# Javascript is not working in IE 11, even alert is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-11, alert

This code is not working in IE11 its working fine in other browsers even in Ie edge, but not working in IE 11.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//used for allow unicode and char count
        //var countedTextBox = document.getElementById("counttxt");
        var check1 = document.getElementById('allowunicode');
        var limitVal = document.getElementById('totalchar');
        var textArea1 = document.getElementById('txtmsg');
        var charEntered = document.getElementById('countBody');

        alert("1");
        check1.addEventListener('click', () => {
          if (check1.checked) {
            limitVal.innerHTML = '268';
            checkMaxLimit(268);
          } else {
            limitVal.innerHTML = '620';
            checkMaxLimit(620);
          }
        });
alert("2");
        function checkMaxLimit(limit) {
          if (textArea1 && textArea1.value.length > limit) {
              textArea1.value = textArea1.value.substring(0, limit);
            alert('Sorry! You have reached your maximum message limit.');
          }

        }

        textArea1.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
          var chhhr = textArea1.value.length;
          checkMaxLimit(+limitVal.innerHTML);
          if (chhhr.value >= limitVal) {
            //alert('Maximum value reached');
            charEntered.innerHTML = limitVal.innerHTML;
          }else{
          charEntered.innerHTML = textArea1.value.length;
          }

    });

</script>
```

Above code is not working In IE11, I have tried with a simple alert box but even alert is not working in IE11.

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in IE. Replace `() => {}` with regular `function() {}`

Comment: What should i use instead of arrow

Comment: But alert is also not working, alert has simple function, why alert is not working ?

Comment: Replace the arrow functions with regular `function`. Press F12 and check the console for errors. Add breakpoints and debug. `alert` is not working in IE is simply not reporducible

Comment: Just replace " () =>{ " with " function()  { " and this will work in IE 11